# how can i pass a php variable from parent page to include page

Tags: php

I am including a page `childpage.php` in my parent page, I want to pass a variable from parent page to `childpage.php` and I also want to access this variable in my `childpage.php`. Here is my code:

```
include_once("childpage.php?a='$x'");
```

Why doesn't this work?

Comment: Surely you can just do `include_once("childpage.php?a=$x");` ?

Comment: Once you included file you can access your variable simply in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just define the variable before the include so

```
$x = 'something that is needed in the include file';
include_once("childpage.php");
```

You can use the `$x` variable in `childpage.php` now.

Answer (score 3):

It's a question of scope. Any variables you have in parent.php will be visible in childpage.php :-

```
<?php // parent.php

$var1 = "Hello";
include_once("childpage.php");

?>

<?php // childpage.php

echo $var1;

?>
```